# Changing font face of a ListView without SimpleAdapter in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to change the font face of the list items in my ListView. I created a custom items for that because I want to let the user see the basic information on the database from that activity. How can I change the fonts of my views?

MainActivity.java

```
//Method in that fetch the data to list view
private void displayListView() {
    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    Cursor cursor = db.fetchClinicByName("");

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] { Constants.CLINIC_ID, Constants.CLINIC_NAME, Constants.CLINIC_ADD };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textviewId, R.id.tv_ClinicName, R.id.tv_ClinicAdd };

    simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.attribute_clinic, cursor, columns, to, 0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_clinic);

    listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
```

attribute_clinic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clinic Name:"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ClinicName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:text="clinic"/>

    </TableRow> 

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clinic Address:"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ClinicAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:text="clinicAdd"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    </TableRow>         
</LinearLayout>  

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="114dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Do you plan on using this custom font in other places also, or only here? The reason why I'm asking is because you can either extend TextView and modify to change the font (good idea if you plan on using this custom font elsewhere), or you could override setViewText (which works well just for this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not actually tried this yet, but I believe this should work.

You need to override SimpleCursorAdapter's `setViewText()`. It would be something like this when your fonts are inside of your assets/fonts folder.

```
private void displayListView() {
    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    Cursor cursor = db.fetchClinicByName("");

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] { Constants.CLINIC_ID, Constants.CLINIC_NAME, Constants.CLINIC_ADD };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textviewId, R.id.tv_ClinicName, R.id.tv_ClinicAdd };

    simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.attribute_clinic,
                                                  cursor, columns, to, 0) {
        @Override
        public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {
            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/yourfont.ttf");
            v.setTypeface(face);
            v.setText(text);
        }
    };

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_clinic);

    listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
```